# app crash without any logs and freeze overall mobile phone for a while after crash

Tags: flutter, dart, memory-management, crash

I am building an ecommerce app... after some events in app like listview scroll and some page navigations the app crashes without any logs and freeze overall mobile phone for a while... can someone give me hint how can i detect that why my app crashes and why it freeze phone

Answer (score 1):

you can try Devtools Performance View.
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/performance
It's only for mobile devices.
So you can figure out, when your CPU get in trouble,
with CPU Profiler.(for example)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have used addListener and forgot to removeListener.[enter link description here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier/addListener.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i never used addListener in app

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).